# Using yq to edit yaml files (--in-place, -i flag)

Tags: yaml, edit-in-place, yq

I'm having a big problem with the edit in place flag for yq version 2.12.0.
We are trying to update a value for a variable in one of our .yaml scripts. The before looks like this...

```
authentication:
  anonymous:
    enabled: false
```

But we want this

```
authentication:
  anonymous:
    enabled: true
```

We have tried to run

```
sudo yq -y ".authentication.anonymous.enabled |= true" sample.yml
```

but it overwrites the entire file and just makes it blank :/
Our current workaround is to run

```
sudo yq -y ".authentication.anonymous.enabled |= true" sample.yml > newfile.yml
sudo cp newfile.yml sample.yml
```

So basically we create the correct output we want but just push it into a new file and then copy the new contents into the old file (I know it's a whole ordeal). There's gotta be a better way to accomplish this...Can someone show me how to edit the file using the yq --in-place flag properly?

Comment: Maybe try upgrading since 2.12.0 is two major versions behind of current 4.7.1, which does have `-i`

Comment: Are you using Python yq as opposed to the Go version mikefarah/yq ?

Answer (score 22):

#### yq - written in Go

Using [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) you can edit a file in place:

`yq -i e '.authentication.anonymous.enabled |= true' sample.yml`

---

#### yq - written in Python

[yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) does offer in place editing of yaml files :

From README.MD:

```
 With -y/-Y, files can be edited in place like with sed -i: yq -yi .foo=1 *.yml
```

`yq -yi '.authentication.anonymous.enabled |= true' sample.yml`

Comment: These are not "yq implementations" -- they're different programs that use the same name but have a slightly different syntax for both the expressions and their respective command lines. If you treat them as "implementations" you'll have to learn the fact the hard way. If only because the Python `yq` wraps `jq` with everything that entails.

Comment: Apologies if I came off rude. But I believe it's best to avoid confusion caused by calling them merely "implementations". I'd use "_the_ `yq`, written in Go by Mike Farah" and "a different  `yq` written later in Python". For lack of better idea. I am nitpicking, admittedly, but people will otherwise think the two are compatible. They are not.

Comment: Thanks for your legitimate comment. I corrected the misleading headlines